# Product of Dedekind cuts: why it is defined in that way?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

A Dedekind cut is a partition of $\mathbb{Q}$ into two proper subsets $A,B$ such that each member of $A$ is smaller than each member of $B$, and $A$ has no largest element.

For Dedekind cuts $(A,B)$ and $(A',B')$, the addition is little natural: it is $(A+A',B+B')$. But the multiplication is little tedious. (I didn't find any rigorous explanation for *defining* multiplication). In the book **Which Numbers are Real** by *Michael Henle* (p.45), the author says

> The multiplication of Dedekind cuts is not simple. The problem is determining sign of a product.

Now, the determination of *sign* in the product which we visit first time is for integers. I saw the link of [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(mathematics)#Product_of_two_integers). It is stated, after the rules of sign for integers, that

> this rule (of sign for product of integers) is a necessary consequence of demanding distributivity of multiplication over addition, and is not an additional rule.

By this comment, I thought that we can focus simply first for product of *positive integers* (with $0$) and with above *necessary rule* of sign, we can completely define the product of all the integers.

Now, similarly, we may think that, we can try to define the product of *positive Dedekind cuts*, and then with the rule of sign, we can define product of all Dedekind cuts.

However, I didn't find any natural way to get the definition of multiplication of two positive Dedekind cuts; why it is defined in that way? Can anybody give me some natural way to define the product of positive Dedekind cuts?

Answer (score 3):

The reason that Dedekind cuts are awkward for negative reals is that multiplication
by negative numbers is not order-preserving.

Consider Dedekind cuts $(A,B)$, $(A',B')$ representing reals $>0$. Then
$A\cap\Bbb Q^+$ and $A'\cap\Bbb Q^+$ are nonempty, where $\Bbb Q^+=\{x\in\Bbb Q:x>0\}$.
Their product is $(A'',B'')$ where
$$A''=\{x\in \Bbb Q:x\le 0\}\cup\{aa':a\in A\cap\Bbb Q^+,a\in A'\cap\Bbb Q^+\}.$$

The rationale is that
$$A''\cap\Bbb Q^+=\{aa':a\in A\cap\Bbb Q^+,a\in A'\cap\Bbb Q^+\}.$$
This works just like addition, expect we restrict attention to positive numbers,
where multiplication is order-preserving.